# A quick question regarding integral notation.

Tags: integration, notation

Say a particle is traveling along the parameterized curve $\left(X,Y\right)$, where $X$ and $Y$ are functions of time. I want to find the distance it has traveled as a function of time. The solution would be something like this: 
$$\int_0^t\sqrt{\dot{X}^2+\dot{Y}^2}\,dt$$
This integral is with respect to $t$, and the integral is on the interval $[0,t]$. Is it correct to have $t$ in both places? I would like to avoid using another variable.

Comment: I don't think this is a question. If you don't want to use another symbol what can the answer tell you?

Comment: Not really... I'd either leave the bounds blank or use different bounds or variables.

Comment: It is incorrect, though $[t_0, t_1]$ is a common standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not correct.  You're forcing $t$ to have an out-of-body experience.  It has to go to $0$ and travel back to itself.  There's no getting out of a new variable.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help :)

Comment: This is my new favorite way of describing this error.